# Porting java applets to cross platform applications using libGDX

Tags: java, applet, libgdx, porting

Would libGDX be the best thing to do if have have some applets(with a lot of UI code in it and animations as well), and I want to port them to a cross platform architecture, with minimum changes in code?
I know the UI code must be changed completely. But would this be the best method to follow?

Comment: Which platforms are you targeting?

Comment: well, mostly, android and desktop (android is of more priority, hence the importance on porting). Will it be easier to recode in android than libGDX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because libgdx has many advantages, you can easily port your applets to libgdx and it would run in Html5, Android, Windows, Mac, Linux and iOS.

Making animations and a UI is not hard, totally worth your time.